How to use Python to display the information about computers in Windows?
I want to use Python to display some information about my computer, such as CPU usage, memory usage, internet speed monitoring etc. And use a tool like tkinter to fix the display in the top right corner of the screen.
I tried to implement this feature, but the actual result is not satisfactory. For example, the background is not transparent and the font does not fit my needs. Also, it seems a bit too monotonous. For example, it can't alert me when it's highly occupied by modifying the font colour, pop-ups, etc.; the simple display of no symbols is not concise enough... There may even be a number of performance issues and it doesn't seem to be working right now! All in all, it's a failure.
My project code(no comments):
import psutil
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def get_cpu_usage():
    cpu_percent = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
    return f"CPU: {cpu_percent}%"

def get_memory_usage():
    mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    mem_percent = mem.percent
    mem_total = round(mem.total / (1024 ** 3), 2)
    mem_used = round(mem.used / (1024 ** 3), 2)
    return f"Memory: {mem_used}GB / {mem_total}GB ({mem_percent}%)"

def update_taskbar_label(label):
    while True:
        cpu_text = get_cpu_usage()
        mem_text = get_memory_usage()
        label.config(text=f"{cpu_text}   {mem_text}")
        label.update_idletasks()

def close_window(event):
    root.destroy()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Taskbar Monitor")

    screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

    window_width = 512
    window_height = 64

    x = screen_width - window_width
    y = screen_height - window_height - 64

    root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.attributes("-alpha", 0.7)

    label = tk.Label(root, font=("Msyh", 14))
    label.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    thread = threading.Thread(target=update_taskbar_label, args=(label,))
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    root.bind("<Escape>", close_window)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I don't understand what do you want to fix. Do you want to know how to change the font, know if it is optimized or something else ?

Your code is working. Close the Browser, then you can see on the bottom right side.

I’m voting to close this question because the code is working, so you can see the display on the bottom right side.
